# Can I optimize this game tick loop better?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe

I set .rate to 10 earlier, so I'm looking to update the game logic every 10 frames.

Is there an optimized way to accomplish this?

I understand many game loops use deltatime without explicitly caring about frames -- I'd rather avoid this as my game logic depends on input variance from 1 frame to the next (player inputs are recorded in incremental units which makes the playback easier).

If the delta time exceeds multiple rates, the draw call which updataes the HTML5 canvas only is called once after all of the logic updating.

```
loop() {
    this.now = Date.now();
    var delta  = this.now - this.last;
    this.last = this.now;

    this.dt = this.dt + delta;

    if (this.dt < this.rate) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this));
        return;
    }

    while (this.dt > this.rate) {
        this.game.loop(delta);  
        this.dt -= delta;
    }

    this.draw();

    this.loopInput();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: -1 and close vote with no comment, why? I got the very frame for this code from another SO post and I'm looking to optimize. The other answers never gave full examples / explanations.

Comment: If you need to worry about framerate (frames per second) then you will have to eventually synchronize against the clock. If you're just concerned with the ratio of rendering-to-logic frames, you can use integer counters in the per-frame logic. I don't think you can improve much on the timing / sync logic.

Comment: The first close vote was because the voter felt the question to be "too broad", which it is given that "optimise" is a pretty vague goal, but I was thinking I'd vote to close it as "off topic" because in my opinion "help optimise this working code" questions belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize SE had gotten so specialized. Thanks for the CR link.

Answer (score 0):

hmm if you only care about updating your game logic every 10 frames, why not do this:

```
var i = 0;
loop() {
 i++;
 if(i < 10){
  i++;
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  return;
 }
 //actual rendering logic here
 i = 0;
}

requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

As an interesting aside, the current time in which the callback is fired is passed as an argument to your callback function according to mdn. This means that you don't need to use Date.now()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame